# Populate Chart on Web page with data obtained from Oracle DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I'm trying to update a page to show a line chart from data retrieved using PHP from an oracle DB. I'm having difficulty grasping how to get the chart to appear on the page.

I am utilizing Chart.js to build the chart. My PHP pulls data from the database where I'd like it to use that data to call a JavaScript function and populate the chart and then post it back on the page with the click of a button.

The first part I am stuck on is getting the chart to populate with even static data. I am able to get a table to appear utilizing HTML, but getting the chart to populate I need to send back a call to the JS function I believe.... any tips?

In my html I have the functions below

```
function loadChart() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("charthere").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","php/fill_counts_graph.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}



function chart() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["10/02/2017", "10/03/2017", "10/04/2017", "10/05/2017", "10/06/2017", "10/07/2017"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Fills',
            data: [86452, 90452 ,55246 , 44179,78442 ,12546 ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});



}
```

I have setup the canvas as below

```
<canvas id='myChart' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/Chart.js'></script>
<div id="charthere"><b>Chart Goes Here....</b></div>
```

and I have a button in a form as below

```
<button id="graph" type="button" onclick="loadChart();">Graph</button>
```

In a PHP file, I have the below line trying to call the function in the html and populate the chart on the screen

```
echo "<script>chart();</script>";
```

If I were to put that line in the html alone, it would work.

Full HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("envSelect").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","php/fill_counts_graph_list.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

function load_envs() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("envSelect").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","php/fill_counts_graph_list.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}


function generate(start,end,env) {
    if (start == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","php/fill_counts_table.php?sdate="+start+"&edate="+end+"&env="+env,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }


}

function loadChart() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("charthere").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","php/fill_counts_graph.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}



function chart() {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["10/02/2017", "10/03/2017", "10/04/2017", "10/05/2017", "10/06/2017", "10/07/2017"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Fills',
            data: [86452, 90452 ,55246 , 44179,78442 ,12546 ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});



}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<form>
    <input type="date" name="sdates">
    <input type="date" name="edates">
    <input type="test" name="envNames">
<button id="main_update" type="button" onclick="generate(sdates.value,edates.value,envNames.value);">Load</button>
<button id="envs" type="button" onclick="load_envs();">env</button>
<button id="graph" type="button" onclick="loadChart();">Graph</button>

</form>
<br>
<div id="envSelect" name="envNames"><b>Env Selector...</b></div>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Environment info will be listed here...</b></div>
<canvas id='myChart' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/Chart.js'></script>
<div id="charthere"><b>Chart Goes Here....</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Full PHP code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 40%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if (isset($_GET['sdate'], $_GET['edate'])) {

$sdate =  filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'sdate', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$edate = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'edate', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$env = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'env', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

#$sdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($sdateO);
#$edate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($edateO);

$conn = oci_connect('cmdb', 'cmdb', 'HOST/cmdb');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

#$sql = "SELECT DOMAIN, FACILITY_COUNT, FILL_COUNT FROM env_daily_stats WHERE domain like ('%p0%') AND type = 'TRexOneWeb' AND TRUNC(datestamp) BETWEEN TO_DATE('" . $sdate . "','MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('" . $edate . "','MM/DD/YYYY')";
$sql = "";



$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

// The defines MUST be done before executing
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'DATESTAMP', $datestamp);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'CUSTOMER_NAME', $domain);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'ERXFILLS', $fillCount);
#oci_define_by_name($stid, 'FILL_COUNT', $fillCount);

oci_execute($stid);

// Each fetch populates the previously defined variables with the next row's data
echo "<h1>Fill Counts from " . $sdate . " to " . $edate . "</h1>";
echo "<script>chart();</script>";


oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the code you're referring to when referencing things. Can't exactly answer with nothing to start with.

Comment: Thanks I added code. There is extra in there and of course I removed any connection info and my SQL... The other code in there works fine when the SQL and CONN are entered. I'm thinking I need to implement other routes to do this, but was hoping I could get this to work...